# How to check if wifi connected is static or not programatically in android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I use the connection manager class and get the network info, I just get if network type is Wifi or ethernet. But When my network type is Wifi, I would like to know if its static or dynamic.

Can someone help me out with this

Comment: Are you talking about static/dynamic IP addresses?

Comment: ya ipsettings as static

Comment: If some one know about static Ip settings le tme know.. I need to programatically check if my wifi or ethernet is takign static IPSettings or not

Answer (score 2):

below You can find simple (not optimised) code adapted from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136000/assign-static-ip-address-for-wifi-network-on-android-3-x-and-4-x). 
Code is written for Android 4.0.

Remember to add additional user permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Method:

```
public String getIpAssignment(){

    String myenumvalue="";
    WifiConfiguration wifiConf = null;
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();        
    for (WifiConfiguration conf : configuredNetworks){
        if (conf.networkId == connectionInfo.getNetworkId()){
            wifiConf = conf;
            break;              
        }
    }
    if(wifiConf != null){

        try {
            Object Enumer = getDeclaredField(wifiConf, "ipAssignment");
            myenumvalue = Enumer.toString();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


    }

    return myenumvalue;
}
```

It returns one of enum fields from ipAssignment: UNASSIGNED | STATIC | DHCP

Answer (score 0):

my android test device android version 5.1.1(embedded board)
I used the code above, but it fell into the error
("catch NoSuchFieldException")

i use this code to find static or dhcp connection:

```
 public void getWifiDhcpStatic(){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo connectionInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration conf : configuredNetworks){
        if (conf.networkId == connectionInfo.getNetworkId()){
            if (conf.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("DHCP".toLowerCase())>-1){
                Log.i("myLogDHCPorSTATIC","DHCP ");

            }else if(conf.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("STATIC".toLowerCase())>-1){
                Log.i("myLogDHCPorSTATIC","STATIC ");

            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```