# Assign static IP address for Wifi network on Android 3.x and 4.x

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, ipv4

Im working on one project and there should be a functionality for setting static IP address (DNS, Netmask, Gateway) for `Wifi` if user want it.

**My initial and actual solution** is an usage of `android.provider.Settings.System` class that allows this feature but this solution works successfully only for Android 2.x devices.

It's nice, definitely i'm not on totally zero but it would be nice to get it work also for higher versions of Android OS. It don't know exactly why it doesn't work.

If i use this simple method for checking actual status:

```
public static final boolean hasStaticIp(Context c) {
    try {
        return Settings.System.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), 
                                        Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP) == 1;
    }
    catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Settings not found (" + e.geMessage() + ")");
        return false;
    }
}
```

it returns true for both Android 2.x and also Android 4.x but in second case, changes are definitely not reflected in `Wifi` I found [this a little hardcoded solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-static-ip-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-android-3-x-or-4?lq=1) but it didn't work as expected.

Is there anyone that faced against same problem?

I'll be glad for any working solution and also for rooted devices (maybe some command in linux) since it's easy to check status of whether cellphone is rooted or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now i can say: *"I caught it"*

I spent many days by looking for better, cleaner and for 100% working solution how actual (now i guess currently only one solution) solution with reflection is. But without result.

So i tried again to use mentioned solution with reflection here:

- [How to configue static IP, netmask ,gateway programmatically on
  Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-static-ip-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-android-3-x-or-4?lq=1)

and suprisingly it works! And now i know what i was missing. So everyone who tried this solution on device with `API` greater than **10** (sice Honeycomb) make sure you called:

```
wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
```

it's not enough to call only

```
wifiManager.updateNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
```

bacause changes (also made via reflection) won't be permanently saved to specific **WifiConfiguration**.

So now it works as expected and now a little summary:

### Setting static IP address for Android 1.x and 2.x :

Android 1.x and 2.x doesn't provide solution for setting static ip address per SSID (only for actual connected network) so simple working solution is to use **ContentResolver** and write data to **System Settings** via:

```
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, "wifi_use_static_ip", 1); // enabling static ip
Settings.System.putInt(resolver, "wifi_use_static_ip", 0); // enabling DHCP
```

### Setting static IP address for Android 3.x and 4.x:

Since Android 3.x it's possible to set static ip address per SSID hence solution for lower versions of Android OS will not working.

Currently there is no `API` for this purpose so solution with reflection linked above is only one that actually works.

### Notes:

Don't forget to change `setGateway()` for Android 3.x (also mentioned in origin thread)

Finally since if someone want to have application for setting static ip adress for Android 3.x and 4.x proper method takes **netmask prefix as int** and **not full netmask** so [here is list of available netmasks](http://www.gadgetwiz.com/network/netmask.html) with their prefixes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Android L (5.0) preview this seems to break for me (I'm only reading the values to determine if static or DHCP, not altering). If anyone finds a Android L solution - please share.

Comment: `wifiManager.saveConfiguration();` is a great tip