# Trying to find a solution in Android 12 to detect if DHCP or STATIC ip is used. Non of the answers on stack overflow has worked for me

Tags: android, ip, dhcp

I'm trying to programmatically detect if the IP that is used, in this case by a payment terminal based on Android 12, is obtained by DHCP or declared STATIC.

The requirement is to show a string (DHCP or STATIC) in a menu.

There are two different versions of the terminal, one that has Wifi support and one that has ethernet support.

I have tried below solutions without success.

[Determine if IP Address is STATIC or DHCP using Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57624831/determine-if-ip-address-is-static-or-dhcp-using-android)

[How to check if wifi connected is static or not programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756248/how-to-check-if-wifi-connected-is-static-or-not-programatically-in-android)

Comment: ??? Where is this about? What information? Write a decent post please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.